# forEach Looping through objects and printing with document.write();

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, document.write

There is an array, composed of several objects that I need to loop through (preferably using a forEach loop, which is the scope of the exercise). I need to print their details on-screen (can't only see them on console, which would have been far more straightforward) and, ideally, have instruments to format them with CSS.

The closer I could get with a practical forEach loop (see below, try-1), was to print a full sequence of [object Object] pairs, without being able to go a level deeper to retrieve the data.

I've managed to print the details of each object (try-2), but only through a cumbersome listing of each property manually called.

Is there a way I can loop through the object and retrieve its data in an orderly fashion and print it in the screen? Thanks in advance

````
var bulbasaur = { name: "Bulbasaur", height: 0.7, weight: 6.9, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Grass", " Poison"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Grass"], abilities: ["Chlorophyll", " Overgrow"]};

var ivysaur = { name: "Ivysaur", height: 1, weight: 13, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Grass", " Poison"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Grass"], abilities: ["Chlorophyll", " Overgrow"]};

var venusaur = { name: "Venusaur", height: 2, weight: 100, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Grass", " Poison"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Grass"], abilities: ["Chlorophyll", " Overgrow"]};

var charmander = { name: "Charmander", height: 0.6, weight: 8.5, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Fire"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Dragon"], abilities: ["Blaze", " Solar-power"]};

var charmeleon = { name: "Charmeleon", height: 1.1, weight: 19, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Fire"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Dragon"], abilities: ["Blaze", " Solar-power"]};

var charizard = { name: "Charizard", height: 1.7, weight: 90.5, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Fire", " Flying"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Dragon"], abilities: ["Blaze", " Solar-power"]};

var squirtle = { name: "Squirtle", height: 0.5, weight: 9, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Water"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Water 1"], abilities: ["Rain-dish", " Torrent"]};

var wartortle = { name: "Wartortle", height: 1, weight: 22.5, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Water"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Water 1"], abilities: ["Rain-dish", " Torrent"]};

var repository = [
  bulbasaur,
  ivysaur,
  venusaur,
  charmander,
  charmeleon,
  charizard,
  squirtle,
  wartortle
];


(try-1)

const keys = Object.entries(repository)

keys.forEach(function(item, key) {
  document.write(repository[key] + '<br>');
  document.write(item);
});```

try-2
```repository.forEach(function(pokemon){
  document.write('<p class="pokeTitle">' + pokemon.name + '</p>' +
                 'Height: ' + pokemon.height + '<br>' +
                 'Weight: ' + pokemon.weight + '<br>' +
                 'Hatch Steps: ' + pokemon.hatchSteps + '<br>' +
                 'Types: ' + pokemon.types + '<br>' +
                 'Egg Groups: ' + pokemon.eggGroups + '<br>' +
                 'Abilities: ' + pokemon.abilities + '<br>');
});```

(results using try-1)
[object Object]
0,[object Object][object Object]
1,[object Object][object Object]
2,[object Object][object Object]
3,[object Object][object Object]
4,[object Object][object Object]
5,[object Object][object Object]
6,[object Object][object Object]
7,[object Object]

(results using try-2)
Bulbasaur

Height: 0.7
Weight: 6.9
Hatch Steps: 5100
Types: Grass,Poison
Egg Groups: Monster,Grass
Abilities: Chlorophyll, Overgrow
(+other 7 pokemon items)
````

Comment: try `document.write(JSON.stringify(item,null,2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to see the actual data would be to use `JSON.stringify` to convert the data to a string.

```js
var bulbasaur = { name: "Bulbasaur", height: 0.7, weight: 6.9, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Grass", " Poison"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Grass"], abilities: ["Chlorophyll", " Overgrow"]};
var ivysaur = { name: "Ivysaur", height: 1, weight: 13, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Grass", " Poison"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Grass"], abilities: ["Chlorophyll", " Overgrow"]};
var venusaur = { name: "Venusaur", height: 2, weight: 100, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Grass", " Poison"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Grass"], abilities: ["Chlorophyll", " Overgrow"]};
var charmander = { name: "Charmander", height: 0.6, weight: 8.5, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Fire"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Dragon"], abilities: ["Blaze", " Solar-power"]};
var charmeleon = { name: "Charmeleon", height: 1.1, weight: 19, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Fire"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Dragon"], abilities: ["Blaze", " Solar-power"]};
var charizard = { name: "Charizard", height: 1.7, weight: 90.5, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Fire", " Flying"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Dragon"], abilities: ["Blaze", " Solar-power"]};
var squirtle = { name: "Squirtle", height: 0.5, weight: 9, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Water"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Water 1"], abilities: ["Rain-dish", " Torrent"]};
var wartortle = { name: "Wartortle", height: 1, weight: 22.5, hatchSteps: 5100, types: ["Water"], eggGroups: ["Monster", " Water 1"], abilities: ["Rain-dish", " Torrent"]};

var repository = [
  bulbasaur,
  ivysaur,
  venusaur,
  charmander,
  charmeleon,
  charizard,
  squirtle,
  wartortle
];

document.querySelector('#repository').textContent = JSON.stringify(repository,null,2);
```

```html
<pre id="repository"></pre>
```

---

If you want to generate HTML though, it might be simpler/more powerful to just use a template engine like [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)/[Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: took some time to answer because I wanted to be sure that there would be no other way to solve this better. I believe stringify is the best call here. THanks!